# How to transfer JSON files(containing test execution results) from my local system to a azure VM (Linux) or to a storage disk attached to a webserver.

Tags: json, azure, file, cloud, transfer

It would be a great help if someone could recommend an easier approach to this using Java.

[Current Framework Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDfDs.jpg)

[Expected Framework Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfQa3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really shared any code or deep technical details, so I can only answer on high level.

On your first screenshot, you have an arrow, where you copy back the test execution result to your localhost. You have to modify this logic, instead of copying back to localhost you have to upload the test executions files to azure storage account. You'll need blob storage to store your files. If you want to do it with Java, here is some sample code with Java v7 about how to upload files to blob storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java

After you uploaded the files to azure storage, you can access the JSON files from your web server. Or, if you make your container public, you won't even need the web server to access these files.